# Copy on Write for References

Tags: perl

Perl currently supports [Copy on Write (CoW)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlguts.html#Copy-on-Write) for scalar variables however it doesn't appear to have anything for hashrefs and arrayrefs.

Perl does, however, have subroutines to modify variable internals like [weaken](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#weaken) so I'm guessing that there might exist a solution.

I have a situation where I have a large structure I'm returning from a package which keeps an internal state of this large structure. I want to ensure that if either the returned references or the internal reference (which are both currently the same reference) is modified that I end up with a Copy-on-write situation where the data the references are pointing to is copied, modified and the reference used to modified the data is updated to point to the new data.

```
package SomePackage;
use Moose;

has some_large_internal_variable_ref => (
    'is'  => 'rw',
    'isa' => 'HashRef',
);

sub some_operation {
    my ($self) = @_;
    $self->some_large_internal_variable_ref({
        # create some large result that is different every time
    });
}

sub get_result {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return $self->some_large_internal_variable_ref;
}

1;

use strict;
use warnings;
use SomePackage;
use Test::More;

# Situtation 1 where the internally stored reference is modified
# This will pass!

my $package = SomePackage->new();
$package->some_operation();
my $result1 = $package->get_result();

$package->some_operation();
my $result2 = $package->get_result();

isnt($result1, $result2, "These two references should no longer be the same");


# Situtation 2 where the externally stored references is modified
# This will fail

$package = SomePackage->new();
$package->some_operation();
$result1 = $package->get_result();
$result1->{foo} = "bar";

$result2 = $package->get_result();

isnt($result1, $result2, "These two references should no longer be the same");

done_testing;
```

I'm trying to avoid a situation where I have to clone the values on the `get_result` return as this would result in a situation where memory usage is doubled.

I'm hoping there is some form of `weaken` I can call on the variable to indicate that, should a modification be made to behave with Copy on Write behaviour.

Comment: @ikegami I'm referring to the data the reference points to. If that gets modified from a particular reference I want it to clone the data and update the reference to point to the new data.

Comment: It is possible using `tie`, which will greatly slow things down, especially if you want to do this deeply.

Comment: Clearly, you want `$cow_ref->[0] = 123;` to clone `@{ $cow_ref }`, but should `$cow_ref->[0][0] = 123;` clone `@{ $cow_ref->[0] }`, `@{ $cow_ref }` or nothing at all?

Comment: @ikegami ideally I'd want just the parts that are modified to clone as I may have an arrayref of hashrefs which contain other hashrefs all the way down. However I can appreciate that this sort of complicated reference splitting might not exist either in internals or in userland. I'm happy to deal with a clone of the entire dataset.

Comment: You can do it deeply yet not copy the entire data set (i.e. clone parents, but not siblings), and it's not and harder than cloning the entire dataset. It is, however, much harder than cloning a the array, so it's much more complicated than string CoW.

Comment: I'd like to adjust what I said earlier. I think it's possible using `tie` and overloaded `=`, but we're talking about a lot work. And I repeat, using `tie` will slow things down considerably.

Comment: Yeah I think this requires a restructuring on the internal behaviour of my package to solve and not a language trick. Thanks for the help in working through this @ikegami

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/raw/s2wXM1Fp) is what the mechanism would be for just array CoW (as opposed to whole data structure CoW). It's not mentioned, but the backreferences would be weak references.